# How to force browsers to show or download non-text/html error pages or other files instead of friendly messages by browsers

Tags: php, .htaccess, browser, http-status-codes

I configured my web site to return non-text/html error "pages" using PHP for some specific reasons. (Cryptography-related content)

Example:
http://ochaken.net/.DS_Store

Returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 33554432
```

Codes:

```
<?php
$protocol = $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'];
header("$protocol 403 Forbidden");
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");

// no cache, dynamic content
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jun 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");

// large file
$bytes = 65536 * 32; // force download of 33,554,432 bytes
header("Content-Length: $bytes");

echo read_error_contents($bytes); // prints contents
```

.htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /***.php
ErrorDocument 404 /***.php
ErrorDocument 403 /***.php
```

But both Firefox 28 and Chromium 34 on MacOS X 10.9
shows friendly messages instead of original files or "download".

Can I configure 403 pages to force most browsers to use original contents?
Maybe this is not because its type is text/plain.

Of course, this page is far longer than 512 bytes.

Safari 7.0.1 downloads this. (Even if this is marked as text/plain)

---

Other example:
http://ochaken.net/favicon.ico

Safari downloads this text/plain 403 document and saves as a Windows icon file.

Answer (score 0):

In sites available add the below:

```
ErrorDocument 403 "YOUR ERROR MESSAGE"
ErrorDocument 404 "YOUR ERROR MESSAGE"
ErrorDocument 500 "YOUR ERROR MESSAGE"
```